# ios code signing issue

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I am in a trouble with IOS CodeSigning.

I searched it but i cant find out what is the problem.

**Here is my problems**

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/caCR7.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIkLH.png

My bundle id is correct however it is not working.
Error message is ; "Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Organizer, choose Device tab, and under Provisioning Profiles (first entry in the left panel) you should see your certificates. Are they valid? If not you may be missing private key.

If you go to your Keychain, under Certificates you should see your developer profile. They should be expandable and when you expand you should see there's the private key. Without it the certificate won't be valid.

Comment: Yea according to your second screen shot you don't have private key. Did you switch to a new computer? You need to copy the certificate (including the private key) from your old computer and import it to the new one. If you don't have your old computer, you need to go to the iOS developer portal to regenerate a new key.

Comment: how can i regenerate a new key. i am not sure but i think i did

Comment: @YusufSeyrek, the instructions for doing that are in the developer portal.

Comment: It's in iOS Provisioning Portal. https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action

Comment: btw, you may want to delete the invalid certificate and generate a new one.

Comment: here is my developer portal ss ;http://i.stack.imgur.com/54xGL.png is anything wrong ?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the certificate itself. the problem is you don't have the private key for that certificate. did you switch to a new computer recently? if you did you need to copy the private key over. if you cannot find the private key you need to generate a new certificate (and that will have a private key with it).