# How can I solve the Code Sign error: The identity ipad doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, titanium

I'm new to developing for iOS (hence new to MacOSx) and using Titanium, the version I'm using is 2.1. I tried to deploy my application on an iPad but the following error showed up:

```
[ERROR] Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains
```

When I checked Xcode the Provisioning Profiles have the status `Valid signing identity not found`, my Xcode version is 4.4. I have entered my team developer portal, the application and the iPad are registered there and have downloaded the certificate and the provisioning files and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a) post but I couldn't solve my problem.

I'm really lost here and I wish someone would just guide me in finding the answer to this problem. What I have read so far hasn't given me a solution. Hope anyone can help me with this issue.

Comment: my answer to this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743129/ios-code-signing-issue/11743395#11743395 Basically you need a private key.

Comment: yeah it doesn't have a private key, but I don't have the computer where the CRS was generated, is there another way?

Comment: you need to go to ios provisioning portal, delete your old profile and generate a new one.

Comment: is there a guide I can use to be sure I won't mess with it? The person who did the configuration of the provisioning profiles is away at the moment and I can't reach him right now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: also I just checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989368/add-private-key-to-certificate-or-vice-versa) and it says what I have to revoke is the certificate, that sounds more drastic or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Na, it is pretty dramatic. If you don't have access to a machine with the private key you need, and you don't want to revoke and create a new certificate, then you need to wait for the original person to become available again.

Comment: Also, note for others. If you have two "iPhone Developer" certificates in Keychain Access, you may have an expired one. In my experience deleting the expired one solves the problem.

Comment: I had to import the .p12 file, that didn't make it expandable, but changed its status to valid profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time this problem creeps up for me (when I'm using a new machine or new device), I always refer to this post:

[iPhone app signing: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be)

The answer by Louie always worked for me.
Good luck